# Is there some way to automatically set the --exclusive flag if the user request more than one node?

Tags: slurm, hpc

Asking as an (inexperieneced) admin: Is there some way to configure SLURM to automatically use the --exclusive parameter if users request more than 1 node?

I looked through the documentation and did a fair bit of googling, but so far I did not find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is probably to create a job submit plugin such as [this example from the doc](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/contribs/lua/job_submit.lua) and implement there the logic to add the `--exclusive` option whenever needed.

That being said, you could potentially reach a different but probably sufficiently close situation by setting [ExclusiveUser](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_ExclusiveUser) in `slurm.conf`. This will reduce risks of node fragmentation and at the same time allow for arrays of 1-CPU jobs that do not each need a full node.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into the job submit plugin. The ExclusiveUser approach will not work for us, I think, due to usage patterns and node configuration.